# Event not registering on dynamically generated menus

Tags: c#, winforms

I am generating MenuItems dynamically from a database table in my winforms Application. The Table Names and Id are stored in a Dictionary

```
foreach (var item in TableList.dict)
        {

            var menuItem = new MenuItem() { Text = item.Value };
            viewRawDataToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item.Value);
            menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(item_Click);
            //ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(item.Value);


        }
```

And the Eventhandler is defined as

```
private void item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
    }
```

However the event is not being called i.e On clicking the MenuItem it shows nothing. It should be displaying the MessageBox.

Any ideas where i am wrong?

Comment: You do not add `menuItem` anywhere, you can't click on something that is not displayed...

Comment: viewRawDataToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item.Value);

Comment: You are adding something called tem.Value to the viewRawDataToolStripMenuItem not the MenuItem. And in any case this will be wrong because DropDownItems wants ToolStrip items

Comment: Thanks got it.  Such an apparent error.